# Cisco VPN and .pcf file

Tags: vpn, cisco, openvpn, cisco-vpn

I have few of profiles  .pcf files , and I used them in order to automate the vpmclient connection VIA CLI command

- I have WIN XP server

for example

```
       vpmclient connect "customor_alpha"
```

until now everything is  ok

but I have problem with the last of my profiles - area1.pcf

the problem is when I type in CMD window the following ( to create VPN connection )

```
     vpmclient connect  "area1"
```

after 2 second CISCO window will pop up and ask for password , ( username already defined in window )

please advice what could be the problem , why I get the "CISCO PVN window" ? or maybe I have some in correct syntax in my .pcf file ,

I checked the .pcf file again and again and I couldn't find the problem ?

example of area1.pcf  ( only example - not my real pcf )

```
 [main]
 Description=connection to TechPubs server
 Host=10.10.99.30
 AuthType=1
 GroupName=docusers
 GroupPwd=
 enc_GroupPwd=158E47893BDCD398BF863675204775622C49<SNIPPED>
 EnableISPConnect=0
 ISPConnectType=0
 ISPConnect=
 ISPCommand=
 Username=alice
 SaveUserPassword=0
 UserPassword=
 enc_UserPassword=
 NTDomain=
 EnableBackup=1
 BackupServer=Engineering1, Engineering2, Engineering 3, Engineering4
 EnableMSLogon=0
 MSLogonType=0
 EnableNat=1
 EnableLocalLAN=0
 TunnelingMode=0
 TCPTunnelingPort=10000
 CertStore=0
 CertName=
 CertPath=
 CertSubjectName
 SendCertChain=0
 VerifyCertDN=CN=”ID Cert”,OU*”Cisco”,ISSUER-CN!=”Entrust”,ISSURE-OU!*”wonderland”
 DHGroup=2
 PeerTimeOut=90
 ForceNetLogin=
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SaveUserPassword=0 
UserPassword=
```

Change the former to a `1` (1 equals true), put the password for the connection in the second. Save the file, then change the attributes to be read-only (this way the VPN client can't modify these lines).

This is something that I did at the last place for a connection to a client, so that the users connecting did not have to know the password.

NOTE: If the settings on the server do not allow for saved passwords, you may be required to enter it in every time, even after doing the above.